# How can i make function play to run no stop over the divs and how to make function play stop playing after button stop is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1- I have tried to make the (.up) class (red) keep looping over and over again over the divs after the Play button is clicked but with no success.
2- And I have to somehow stop the (.up) class to be applied from the first function after the button Stop being clicked and be removed all  (. up)classes remaining if any.

Any help? I prefer JavaScript or JQuery.

PS: Ignore my cheeky code on the JS for the button (Stop) to try to perform some kind of result.

Thanks

```js
let sequencing = [["01-01", "02-01", "03-01"],["01-02", "02-02", "03-02"],["01-03", "02-03", "03-03"],["01-04", "02-04", "03-04"]];

$("#play").on("click",function(){ 
  play();

});


function play(){
sequencing.forEach((arr, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.up').removeClass('up');
    arr.forEach(id => $('#' + id).addClass('up'));
  }, i * 1000);
});

}


$("#stop").on("click", function() {

  sequencing.forEach((arr, i) => { setTimeout( () => {
    $(".shadowPlay").addClass("shadowPlay").stop();
    setInterval(function () {
    arr.forEach(id => $("#" + id).removeClass("shadowPlay"));
    }, i * 1);
  
     });

    }, 1);
    
 });
```

```css
.up {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
</div>
<div>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
</div>


<div>
<div id="01-01">01-01</div>
<div id="02-01">02-01</div>
<div id="03-01">03-01</div>

<div id="01-02">01-02</div>
<div id="02-02">02-02</div>
<div id="03-02">03-02</div>

<div id="01-03">01-03</div>
<div id="02-03">02-03</div>
<div id="03-03">03-03</div>

<div id="01-04">01-04</div>
<div id="02-04">02-04</div>
<div id="03-04">03-04</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If using `setTimeout()`, you must build in a conditional check to drop out of it. I would advise using `setInterval()` instead as you cna ten use `clearInterval()` to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#play").on("click", function() {
    play();
  });

  function play() {
    $(".items").data("interval", setInterval(function() {
      var index = 0;
      if ($(".up").length > 0) {
        index = $(".up:last").index() + 1;
      }
      $(".up").removeClass("up");
      $(".items > div")
        .eq(index)
        .add($(".items > div").eq(index + 1))
        .add($(".items > div").eq(index + 2))
        .addClass("up");
    }, 1000));
  }

  $("#stop").on("click", function() {
    clearInterval($(".items").data("interval"));
  });
});
```

```css
.up {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="play">Play</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="stop">stop</button>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div id="01-01">01-01</div>
  <div id="02-01">02-01</div>
  <div id="03-01">03-01</div>
  <div id="01-02">01-02</div>
  <div id="02-02">02-02</div>
  <div id="03-02">03-02</div>
  <div id="01-03">01-03</div>
  <div id="02-03">02-03</div>
  <div id="03-03">03-03</div>
  <div id="01-04">01-04</div>
  <div id="02-04">02-04</div>
  <div id="03-04">03-04</div>
</div>
```

Instead of a sequence array, you can also simply select each group. Using this as your reference allows the Stop and Start to continue cycling from whatever group was last highlighted.

Comment: Thanks very much, ill try to implement it now I can see the path but unfortunately i won't be able to drop the sequencing array as this is how the actual randomization will, in fact, bring the items inside the array.